# Data loss when encrypting and decrypting using libgcrypt and Elgamal

Tags: c, elgamal, libgcrypt

I am using Libgcrypt with Elgamal to encrypt a block of bytes, and I am having 2 problems:

1. When I do not use padding and my block of bytes starts which an zero byte, I lose the first byte during decryption;
2. If I use padding the encryption works well, but when I decrypt the padding is not removed. And apparently the first zero byte still there.

With RSA I am having the same problem :(

My test code is there: [www.tiago.eti.br/storage/post.c](http://www.tiago.eti.br/storage/post.c)
And it do not use padding.

To use padding you need to change:

```
#define PADDING "raw"
```

to

```
#define PADDING "pkcs1"
```

And to change the encryption algorithm change:

```
#define ALG "elg"
```

to

```
#define ALG "rsa"
```

To compile you need to use:

```
gcc -Wall -g post.c -lgcrypt -o post
```

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure I would expect the padding to be removed when the block is decrypted.

Comment: In documentation you can find this:
"Function: gcry_error_t gcry_pk_decrypt (gcry_sexp_t *r_plain, gcry_sexp_t data, gcry_sexp_t skey) 

(...)This function does not remove padding from the data by default. To let Libgcrypt remove padding, give a hint in `flags' telling which padding method was used when encrypting:

          (flags padding-method)"
And I did it. But it did not work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the same question in Libgcrypt mailing list and I had an answer.

Libgcrypt until 1.5.0 does not remove the padding: it recognizes the flags but does nothing with the padding.

So the solution is update Libgcrypt to 1.5.0.